# How do you set a boolean value in Redis?

Tags: ruby, serialization, redis, boolean

When I set a boolean value (`true`) to a key in Redis, the value is coerced to a string (`"true"`).  With memcached, I get back what I put in.  But with Redis it seems to stringify everything.  I can't find any docs on how to fix this boolean issue.  No special boolean_set methods or boolean options.

I'm using Ruby.

Example follows.

Set up:

```
require 'redis'
@redis = Redis.new
```

running in irb:

```
irb(main):034:0> bool = true
=> true
irb(main):035:0> bool
=> true
irb(main):036:0> @redis.set("example", bool)
=> "OK"
irb(main):037:0> @redis.get("example")
=> "true"
irb(main):038:0> @redis.get("example") == bool
=> false
```

Comment: I'm not aware of a boolean redis type; can't you just convert? https://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro

Comment: yes, but if there's a way of not having to type convert, that would be most helpful.  I looked at the doc you shared @DaveNewton and it references bitmaps for booleans.

Comment: Then use a bitmap and convert the integer? But if you're not optimizing for space seems like a string would make more sense.

Comment: @DaveNewton. I guess.  I didn't exactly exhaust the web trying to research it but I did look around for a while before posting.  I won't be surprised if others come along and find this post an answer to their question bc the issue was not easily explained in 30 min of google searches.

Comment: Re-*shrug*. Anecdotally, I searched on "redis data types" and it took me to the Redis docs within the first few hits (if not the first; don't recall). I didn't search for "ruby convert string to boolean" because I already know how, but that'd work too.

Comment: Yes.  And I looked at those docs too. They don't provide a solution.  Alex G below did though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"The Redis String type is the simplest type of value you can associate with a Redis key. It is the only data type in Memcached, so it is also very natural for newcomers to use it in Redis." - it's impossible to do in an "easy" way.

But regarding what for you need it, you can create some class to write/read of any type of data.

For example, how it's implementing in [Rails ActiveRecord Cache](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/cache.rb#L750)

Some simple interpretation of this pretty big class with using of next `Marshal`'s methods: [`dump`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Marshal.html#method-c-dump) and [`load`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Marshal.html#method-c-load)

```rb
class RedisAnyTypesHandler
  def initialize(redis)
    @redis = redis
  end

  def write(key, value)
    @redis.set(key, serialize(value))
  end

  def read(key)
    deserialize(@redis.get(key))
  end

  private

  def serialize(value)
    Marshal.dump(value)
  end

  def deserialize(value)
    Marshal.load(value)
  end
end
```

Now you can play with any type of data:

```rb
> redis_handler = RedisAnyTypesHandler.new(@redis)
> bool = true
=> true
> redis_handler.write('example', bool)
=> "OK"
> redis_handler.read('example') == bool
=> true

> class Foo
>   attr_accessor :foo
> end
=> nil
> foo = Foo.new
=> #<Foo:0x0000556dc19097f8>
> foo.foo = 2
=> 2
> redis_handler.write('example_2', foo)
=> "OK"
> redis_handler.read('example_2').foo
=> 2
```

Comment: Thank you Alex. What a simple solution.  Why not use .to_json and JSON.parse instead of marshall dump and load?  I just tried it and it works.

Comment: @mike_butak One of the best points in Ryby - the ability to select different ways to solve the problem :) As I mentioned in the description -> it's just an example(of many different ways to solve this problem) :)